# i cant find charms bar on my Lenovo ideapad A10

Tags: windows-8

I bought ideapad last week and have been battling to find charms bar to access windows.I am sure they said the device comes pre_installed with Windows8.I have tried swiping from all the corners of this device.  Please help!

Answer (score 0):

There's a setting called **Disable Edge Swipes** that may be of help. Try this:

Navigate to **Control Panel** | **Hardware and Sound** | **Mouse** | **Device Settings** | **Settings**

It could also be located here:

Navigate to **Control Panel** | **Mouse** | **UltraNav** | **TouchPad Settings** | **Application Gestures** | **Edge Swipes** | then check the status of "**Enable Edge Swipes**"

Answer (score 0):

Swipe from the right if using a touchscreen but not the corner. If you use a mouse you move the mouse to the bottom right corner and then slowly move the mouse up; this will show the charms bar.